# HTML Multiple options Select Box Multiple Times on same name

Tags: php, html, arrays

Actually I am working on Education Management System but I am stuck on it.

```
<select name="teachers[]"  multiple="multiple"  class="chosen-select input-xlarge">
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>  
    </select>

    <select name="teachers[]"  multiple="multiple"  class="chosen-select input-xlarge">
        <option value="1">option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>  
    </select>
```

I am using it multiples time but after submission the output look like this

```
[teachers] => Array
    (
       [0] => 1
       [1] => 2
       [2] => 1
       [3] => 2
    )
```

But i need output like this

```
[teachers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
            )
     )
```

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles This way each option will be in its own array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a multidimensional array in the form and setting a fixed value for the first dimension.

```
<select name="teachers[0][]"  multiple="multiple"  class="chosen-select input-xlarge">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>  
</select>

<select name="teachers[1][]"  multiple="multiple"  class="chosen-select input-xlarge">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>  
</select>
```

The concept behind `x[]` is: Make `x` an array and add each selected value to it. So by using `x[0][]` in the first case it becomes: Make `x[0]` an array and add each selected value to it. In the second case it is: Make `x[1]` an array and add the selected values to it - resulting in the desired output.

However, if you used `x[][]`, this would result in every selected item being its own array, as for each item, a new array will be created.

Comment: @SarmadNazir You're welcome! I hope the explanation makes sense

Comment: i just implemented on my form. Form working like a charm...! again Thanks Dude.